# Pass Value From Controller to Model CodeIginter Using Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with Codeigniter. I try to pass value from view to controller and it works. But there is a problem when it passing from controller to model. It didn't return any value into View.

Here is my controller:

```
 public function Edit2G() {
                $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
                $this->load->model("main_model");
                $data['fetch_data_2G_where'] = $this->main_model->fetch_data_2G_id($id);
                $data['id'] = $id;
                $data['title'] = "Update Data 2G";

                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view("pages/Update2G", $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
```

Here is Model

```
 function fetch_data_2G_id($id)
     {
         $get_2G_data_stored_proc = "CALL Get_2G_Data(?)";
         $data = array( 'id' =>$id);
         $query = $this->db->query($get_2G_data_stored_proc, $data);
         $result = $query->result_array();
         return $get_2G_data_stored_proc;
     }
```

And this is my View

```
<h2 align="center"><?=$title ?></h2>
<h3 align="center"><?=$id ?></h3>
<p align="center"><?php echo $fetch_data_2G_where['id'];?></p> //This is a test
<?php echo form_open('posts/update'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php //echo $fetch_data_2G_where['id']; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Site ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="add title" value="<?php //echo $fetch_data_2G_where['site_name'];?>">
</div>
```

This is the stored procedure result

```
id, id_site, site_name, bsc_name, bcf_id, vlan1, vlan2, status,status_vlan  

'1', 'COK008', 'Combat Batylon754','FBTIMIKA-1','BCF-0112', '3677', '3137', '', 'Metro E'
```

This in Error That I got

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal string offset 'id'
>
> Filename: pages/Update2G.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\DapotTimika\application\views\pages\Update2G.php
>   Line: 3 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\DapotTimika\application\controllers\Pages.php
>   Line: 46 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\DapotTimika\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

What I am missing?

PS: the stored procedure only has one parameter (id) to return / get data

Comment: what you are trying to fetch from DB? table name?

Comment: All entire table row

Comment: your query is not working actually.

Comment: what is the measing of this line of code? `$get_2G_data_stored_proc = "CALL Get_2G_Data(?)";`

Comment: Yep maybe that is the problem. I want to input a dynamic variable into stored procedure parameter. I googling it that is the best what I found. Do you have any sugest?

Comment: yep. but that is not a form. It from html anchor that refer to another page (update page) I'm confuse how to get id value and passing it into model. So I use '$this->uri->segment(3)' If you have any suggestion please let me know

Answer (score 0):

in your controller print_r the below line

```
$data['fetch_data_2G_where'] = $this->main_model->fetch_data_2G_id($id);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data['fetch_data_2G_where']);
```

just to see what's the result your query returning. then from your result you can analyse and get the desired results in view.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Guys for the answer, I found the answer.

I Forgot to parse return value from model into array. The code in model and controller is fine.

here is my view code

```
<?php
        if($fetch_data_2G_where->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($fetch_data_2G_where->result_array() as $data)
            {
        ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Site ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="site_id" value="<?php echo $data['id_site'];?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the Result

[image: Output]